# How to implement a bean-post processor that call destroy methods on prototypes?

Tags: java, spring, prototype, spring-ioc

I'm reading Spring documentation and found this

> One possible way to get the Spring container to release resources used
>   by prototype-scoped beans is through the use of a custom bean
>   post-processor which would hold a reference to the beans that need to
>   be cleaned up.

But if bean-post processor holds a reference to the prototype object then Garbage Collector won't clean it and prototypes beans with their resources will reside in a heap until Application Context is close?

Could you clarify it, please?

Answer (score 5):

Spring has an interface you can implement called [DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor.html). Instances of this interface are asked first if a bean needs destruction via the `requiresDestruction()` method. If you return true, you will eventually get called back again with that bean when it is about to be destroyed via the `postProcessBeforeDestruction` method.

What this does is it gives you a chance to clean up that bean's resources. For example if your bean has a reference to a File, you could close any streams you might have open. The important point is your class doesn't hold a reference to the bean that is about to be destroyed, or you'll hold it up from being garbage collected as you've pointed out.

To define a post-processor, you would do something like this

```
@Component
public class MyDestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor implements DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor {
    public boolean requiresDestruction(final Object bean) {
        // Insert logic here
        return bean instanceof MyResourceHolder;
    }

    public void postProcessBeforeDestruction(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        // Clean up bean here.
        // Example:
        ((MyResourceHolder)bean).cleanup();
    }
}
```